# How to find word(combination of text and numeric) in a column - Excel VBA like I have word "IM23569" my first two digit is constant

Tags: excel, vba

I have below column in excel sheet where I want to get filter on word IM**** to get those rows has contain IM*****

[image]

Comment: Build a [tag:dictionary] of keys to be used for [tag:autofilter]'s Criteria1 using [tag:regex].

Comment: Don't need `vba` - just add an auto filter and set it to `*IM*`

Comment: Might need `*IM*` @Dave (but the first `*` might have been lost in the html).

Comment: @Jeeped durn markup...

Comment: If I do filter on *IM* it is taking all words those are contain IM in sentence or word. like one of row contain "impossible" word then it will take it too. I need only combination of txt and numeric value like I showed in example

Comment: You write *my first two digits is contant*.  So just set your filter to `Text Filter` `contains` `IM25`.

Comment: Sorry my bad, My First two word is constant.

Answer (score 1):

On the Home Tab click Sort & Filter. Click on your column and use `*IM*` as filter.

[image: Filter Image]

Answer (score 0):

Use FIND() together with IFERROR() to do this:

```
=IFERROR(FIND("IM",A2),"")
```

The result will be random numbers meaning the exact location of "IM" starting at the first letter.  Or you could make the result "Found" or "Not Found" like this:

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND("IM",A2),"")="","Not Found", "Found")
```

Cheers!